# Creating a word search filter for Webbrowser Control in Win forms C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on children's browser, so I've created a database table called "WordsSearchFilter" which has the column "Blockedwords", these can be added and removed from the form. However, I want the searchbar to check against the Blockedwords and if the searchbar contains a word, I wanna stop navigation the webpage. I've tried implementing the following code, where I've created a list within the code called BlockedWords too, but it doesn't work. Any help, tips or examples would be appreciated greatly.

```
private void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
        { 
  string[] BlockedWordsArray = BlockedWords.ToArray();



            for (int i = 0; i < BlockedWordsArray.Length; i++)


               if (SearchBar.Equals(BlockedWordsArray[i]))

                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    player.SoundLocation = "nono.wav";
                    player.Play();
                    MessageBox.Show("Booyaa Says No!", "Blocked", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand); // Block List Error Message

                }
```

Comment: Instead of using .Equals() method, use .IndexOf() method. And provide a case insensitive comparison type.

Comment: @AbdullahNehir it doesn't allow me to use .IndexOf  in that place

Comment: Get the searchbar's text and use its method. There must be some property gicing the search bar's text.

Comment: @AbdullahNehir  i did  if (SearchBar.Text.IndexOf(BlockedWordsArray[i])) but it gives me an error saying you cannot convert type int to bool.

Comment: @AbdullahNehir  I did,  if (SearchBar.Text.Contains(BlockedWordsArray[i]))  and it worked. But any idea how implement a case insensitive comparison?

Comment: IndexOf returns integer; -1: not found, 0 or larger: searched text is found and the retırned number is the index.

Comment: So, you can use like this: .IndexOf(blockedWordsArray[i], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1

Comment: @AbdullahNehir Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `IndexOf(pattern, StringComparison)` method of string class.
Below is the full code.

```
private void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    string[] BlockedWordsArray = BlockedWords.ToArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < BlockedWordsArray.Length; i++)
    {
        if (SearchBar.Text.IndexOf(BlockedWordsArray[i], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            player.SoundLocation = "nono.wav";
            player.Play();
            MessageBox.Show("Booyaa Says No!", "Blocked", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand); // Block List Error Message
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a for loop for each list item then use an if statement with .contains method to check if it contains any of the list items.

Microsoft documentation and examples here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx